# Simple HTML dom parser is getting the whole file contents and not the content in the selected div

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I am trying to get the contents of a div with the class of code and when this PHP code executes it gets the whole html file and not the specified content. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Regards

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();

$html->load_file($url);

$content = $html->find('.code');

$new = $html->plaintext;

echo nl2br($new);
```

Comment: well, you should `echo nl2br($content);` and not your whole html then ;-)

Comment: nl2br() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ---- this is the error i get when i try tht

Comment: sorry 'bout that, wasnt aware of the return... your problem was, you searched for code correctly, but yet still echoed the complete html. try this instead: `foreach($html->find('.code') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';`

Comment: I just tried that code and then nothing is returned at all ?